# Distribution of time values randomly in a table Excel - Modeling Power Grid

Tags: excel, modeling

I am working on a model of charging load of electric vehicle. I am attaching a link to an excel workbook for your better understanding.

Column B contains random time values
Column G to P represents houses and each house can have 1 car. So the each time values needs to be distributed in one column. Now when a car is plugged in, its load stays constant for 3 cells.

I want excel to randomly distribute these cars e.g. 4 cars to 4 houses and leave others blank.

what i can think of is, to assign each time a random house then use `IF` formula with `AND` function to match random times with time series and second condition to match random houses with columns 1-10. 
the problem i am facing is, the formula gives a value error  and only works in the rows with has random generated time in front of them [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt7b4.jpg). I know there is a very small thing that i am missing. please help me find it

Regards

[workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArYn8TW3_a3d3xZsHcb4e_qsXayi)

Comment: are you trying to achieve something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429701/shifting-a-load-of-electric-vehicle-to-the-next-row-if-a-condition-is-not-fulful) ? | plus, is the value in C6:C9 is the car number or the number of time/house slots needed?

Comment: @p._phidot_, hi, the post you referred to is also mine :) . but that is a different scenario. i that all the cars were added to the same column, irrespective of the number of houses. now each house has its own column and 1 car is assigned to one column. C6:C9 are is the random house numbers (corresponding to columns), i did it to easily match the specific timings with corresponding house

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE)),"",IF(AND(INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE))>=$F6,INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE))<=$F6+TIME(0,30,0)),11,""))
```

The two elements in the `AND` find the house number in column C and return the corresponding time in column B.

The first element compares the time in F to that time. The second element compares the time + 30 minutes to F (three cells). If it's between those two times, it gets an 11.

The `ISNA` makes sure that the house in question is on the list. You could also use an `IFERROR`, but I prefer the precision of `ISNA`.

**Update**

If you want the values to wrap around, you need to `OR` compare to the next day.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE)),"",IF(OR(AND(ROUND($F6,5)>=ROUND(INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE)),5),ROUND($F6,5)<=ROUND(INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE))+TIME(0,30,0),5)),AND(ROUND($F6+1,5)>=ROUND(INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE)),5),ROUND($F6+1,5)<=ROUND(INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE))+TIME(0,30,0),5))),11,""))
```

That formula structure looks like

```
=If(isna(),"",if(or(and(today,today),and(tomorrow,tomorrow)),11,"")
```

This formulas already getting too big. If you triple it for your three voltages, it will be huge. You should consider writing a UDF in VBA. It won't be as quick to calculate, but will probably be more maintainable.

If you want to stick with a formula, you could put the wattage in row 4 above the house number. Then in another table, list the wattages and minutes to charge. So in, say, B12:C14 you have

```
3.7 120
11  30
22  15
```

Now where you have `11` in your formula, you'd have `G$4` and the two placed you have `TIME(0,30,0)`, you'd have `TIME(0,INDEX($C$12:$C$14,MATCH(G$4,$B$12:$B$14,FALSE)),0)`. I re-arranged some stuff to make it more 'readable' (but it's still pretty tough) and here's the final formula

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE)),"",IF(OR(AND(ROUND($F6,5)>=ROUND(INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE)),5),ROUND($F6,5)<=ROUND(INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE))+TIME(0,INDEX($C$12:$C$14,MATCH(G$4,$B$12:$B$14,FALSE)),0),5)),AND(ROUND($F6+1,5)>=ROUND(INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE)),5),ROUND($F6+1,5)<=ROUND(INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH(G$5,$C$6:$C$9,FALSE))+TIME(0,INDEX($C$12:$C$14,MATCH(G$4,$B$12:$B$14,FALSE)),0),5))),G$4,""))
```

Comment: @osk you may complete the steps by "accept"-ing this answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) . and it will remove this question from the 'unanswered' question list. | Either way, if the answer doesn't solves, please share in the comment/post on the issues encountered while implementing it. | Glad that it helps. ( :

Comment: @Dick Kusleika, I have a small problem. actually in my model i use 3 types of chargers, 3.7 kW, 11 and 22. i need also to incorporate that it looks if the charger capacity is 3.7kw it marks 3.7 in 8 cells (because thats how long it takes to charge on 3.7 kw Charger), 3 cells for 11 and 2 cells for 22. how do i do that. my guess is to use nested `IF` but where ?

Comment: EDIT: I did it, just used the formula 3 times in a nested `IF`. but now i have one more question. is it possible that if the time value at the bottom of the list is selected, the values to be filled in the table fills the bottom and then the top of the table? e.g if 12 am is selected as a time, 11 should be filled in 12am, 12:15 and 12:30 (which are on the top of the table)?

Comment: @Dick Kusleika, 1 more question :) , suppose there is only one house and we dont need to match the house numbers with the random house numbers so the only matching criteria is time. how would the formula change ? i dont need multiple charging powers here so just a normal 11 kw, for just one house distributed according to 1 time value but it should wrap.    NOTE: it is a different case but as it is similar so i am asking here.

Comment: One 11kw house with the time in B6 looks like this `=IF(OR(AND(ROUND($F6,5)>=ROUND($B$6,5),ROUND($F6,5)<=ROUND($B$6+TIME(0,30,0),5)),AND(ROUND($F6+1,5)>=ROUND($B$6,5),ROUND($F6+1,5)<=ROUND($B$6+TIME(0,30,0),5))),11,"")`